# How do I access files in /WEB-INF using HTML in a Tomcat server?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, tomcat

Currently I have a website running which allows the user to enter a password into a . The form calls a doPost() to a Java HttpServlet file, which then checks if the field entered was correct or not.

Depending on the condition, it either redirect to TryAgain or Menu page using the following

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/FOLDERNAME/Menu.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
```

This part works okay, but once I am on the Menu page I have two hyperlinks which should redirect to either /WEB-INF/FOLDERNAME/Multi.jsp or /WEB-INF/FOLDERNAME/Single.jsp

I need to keep these pages only accessible by users who signed in successfully on the initial password form page, so I put these inside of my /WEB-INF/ folder.

The problem I am having is how do I redirect to the appropriate page (Multi.jsp/Single.jsp) using HTML? I think it is a bit of an overkill to wire these two hyperlinks to two individual forms and call the request.getRequestDispatcher().forward(); from doPost(){} just to redirect a user.

Is there a different way to go about doing this?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the content. If you give a submit button a name (e.g. "submitButtonA") and value (e.g. "Submit A"), then the button that is used to submit the form will be included in the submitted data (e.g. `...&submitButtonA=Submit+A`). The button that isn't clicked won't be sent. If neither button is clicked (e.g. the form is submitted by pressing return in an input element), then the first button is submitted as if it had been clicked.

Comment: @RobG How terrible of me! You're completely right, and I will reflect changes in order to better match the title and content.

Comment: I am unable to edit my last comment. @RobG, in regards to your answer, how can I obtain this `...&submitButtonA=Submit+a` submitted data?

Comment: @Trent can you explain your last comment little bit clearly ? so that we can understand what you want ?

Comment: You cannot link to a jsp under web-inf with `<a href` nor submit to it with an HTML form, nor call it with Ajax, nor use `response.sendRedirect()` to get to it. You can only forward to it.

Comment: I am wanting to forward from one jsp in WEB-INF to another. The problem is, this page forwards to two separate jsp pages, depending on which link the user clicks. 
If I can only do this using forward, how can I distinguish which link was clicked inside of the doPost() method of my HttpServlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a method, and would like to share it with others.

On my Menu.jsp I created a  with two href attributes

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../FOLDER/menu-servlet?roster">Upload Roster File</a></li>
    <li><a href="../FOLDER/menu-servlet?manual">Manual Order</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This called my HttpServlet doGet() method.
Inside of here, I was able to grab the query string, which is the text following  **?**  in the url.

Then I did a simple if comparison in my doGet() method.

```
 String queryString =request.getQueryString();
       // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       // out.println(request.getQueryString());  

        //check where to redirect
        if (queryString.equals("roster")) {
            //redirect to Roster Upload jsp
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/FOLDER/Roster.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else if (queryString.equals("manual")) {
            //redirect to Manual Generation jsp
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/FOLDER/ManualOrder.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
        }
```